# PYQT5 don't find the designer.exe in the pyqt5_tools folder

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

After one week i was able to install the Pyqt5 I discovered I needed to exit from every Python file, now i in the ./lib/site packages/pyqt5_tools i don't find the designer.exe tools. I have Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

finally found it, is in ./lib/site-packages/pyqt5-tools/qt/bin/